# How to match everything between A and B but don't cross boundaries of predefined word

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression so it match everything starting *"Hello"* up to and including *"everyone"*, with any characters in between. In case of *'and'* found between *'Hello'* and *'everyone'* the expression has to fail.

So this string "Hello you and everyone" has to fail, but this "Hello you everyone" has to match.

I was trying to implement it something like this:

```
Hello.*?((?!and)){1}everyone
```

but it doesn't fail on *and*

https://regex101.com/r/mX51ru/150

Comment: Hi Alexey, please share what you have attempted so far, and what went wrong with your attempts. Also, please provide clear examples of your input and expected output so we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
^(?!Hello.*?\band\b.*?everyone)Hello.*?everyone
```

- `^` matches start of the line
- `(?!Hello.*?\band\b.*?everyone)` is a zero-width negative lookahead pattern to make sure the word `and` does not come in-between `Hello` and `everyone`
- `Hello.*?everyone` matches the desired input having `Hello` and `everyone` in the line

**Example:**

```
In [1925]: str_1 = 'Hello you everyone'                                                                                                                                                                     

In [1926]: str_2 = 'Hello you and everyone'                                                                                                                                                                 

In [1927]: re.search(r'^(?!Hello.*?\band\b.*?everyone)Hello.*?everyone', str_1)                                                                                                                             
Out[1927]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='Hello you everyone'>

In [1928]: re.search(r'^(?!Hello.*?\band\b.*?everyone)Hello.*?everyone', str_2) is None                                                                                                                     
Out[1928]: True
```